Frequent Internet disconnection 24.04
I was facing frequent internet disconnection issue on 22.04. I thought some malware was doing this, did a fresh install of 24.04. Sadly, the issue continues. The Wifi icon says connected, YouTube does not show any " No connection " warning, but won't play any video. The internet comes back if I turn off and ON the WiFi.
The issue is so bad that I cannot enjoy a video on YouTube. If am watching the song, it's disconnected 3 times before I finish it.
I tried a few topics that talk about but found no solution that I could try. At times, the internet works without any issue. Not sure what or where is wrong.
I am using a dual boot (W10) HP Pavilion with 24.04.
Any help will be great. Thanks.

I tried post no. 4 from this support topic
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484635
Looks like it works.The issue was two SSIDs with the same username and password.
